# Get reference to nested map-canvas div in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a weird problem here.I'm sure there is an easy solution, but I can't find it. I am trying to access the div with id "map-canvas" that's nested within another div.

This works:

```
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>  
    <script>
        ...
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas')
    </script>
```

This does not work:

```
<div id="someParentDiv">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>  
</div>  
<script>
    ...
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas')
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, jQuery will not work here either, for some reason.

Comment: Is your HTML valid?  Does it work in a function that runs when the body onload event fires?

Comment: define "does not work"? do you get an error or don't you see the map? When you did not see the map and don't get an error post the relevant CSS

Comment: Doesn't work as in cannot see the map. Anyhow, there is a workaround that requires the height and the width of the container to be hard-coded. Not ideal, but its required by the api.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('someParentDiv').getElementsByTagName('div')[0])
```

Comment: Nope, does not work. There is a workaround that requires the width and height of the parent container to be hardcoded.